# Generate a low-rank sparse covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

May I ask how to generate a low-rank sparse covariance matrix? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using semidefinite programming (SDP)?  Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240875/116107)

Answer (score 0):

You could start from a covariance graph, and use the algorithm described in appendix A of [Model-based clustering with sparse covariance matrices.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07748) This algorithm guarantees the covariance matrix positive definite; the graph gives the rank and degree of sparseness.